# how to send email on contact form submit button click..?

Tags: adobe, osgi, aem

I create component with default component using FormComponent now on submit button click I want to send an email to recently submitted user, I configure SMTP for mail server on :

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr
```

Now I'm stuck how to send email, can someone help me to figure out what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amitavin try asking a clear question you would get help easily.

Anyways as far as I understand your question it seems you don't know how to use the email API. Check this link http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2012-08-20/sending-email-adobe-cq-api/.

Answer (score 0):

write a email service to send email ..I am writing code below for your reference.Code consists of a interface and implementation.

- Please configure Day cq mail service in console/configMgr from ,to,smtp server,userid and password.
- You can use local smtp to test your email functionality.set smpt server in Day CQ email service as localhsot and download smtp4dev from [here](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/).This tool is very useful for testing the email functionality on your local.

  **Hope this is helpfull**

  **Interface**

```js
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;

/**
 *
 * @author Dilip Boddula
 *
 */
public abstract interface EmailService {

  /**
   *
   * @param subject
   * @param message
   * @param to
   * @param from
   * @param cc
   * @throws EmailException
   */
  public void sendSimpleEmail(String subject, String message, String fromAddress, String[] to, String[] cc) throws EmailException;
}
```

and the **Implementation**

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferencePolicy;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MailService;

@Component(label = "E-mail Service", description = "desc.")
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {
    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    private MailService mailService;    
    @Override
    public void sendSimpleEmail(String subject, String message, String fromAddress,String[] to,String[] cc) throws EmailException {
        try {
            List<String> toList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(to));
            List<String> ccList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cc));            
            validateToOrCCAddresses(toList, ccList);

            Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setMsg(message);
            if(null != fromAddress){
             email.setFrom(fromAddress);
            }
            for (String toAddress : toList) {
                email.addTo(toAddress);
            }

            for (String ccAddress : ccList) {
                email.addCc(ccAddress);
            }

            this.mailService.send(email);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EmailException(e);
        }
    }
      private void validateToOrCCAddresses(List<String> toList, List<String> ccList) {
        if ((toList == null) || (toList.isEmpty())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid To Addresses.");
        }
        if (ccList == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid CC Addresses.");
        }

        for (Iterator<String> iterator = toList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String recipient = "";
            try {
                recipient = iterator.next();
                new InternetAddress(recipient);
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Invalid To email address '{}' passed to sendEmail(). Skipping." + recipient, e);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        if (toList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid To Addresses.");
        }

        for (Iterator<String> iterator = ccList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String recipient = "";
            try {
                recipient = iterator.next();
                new InternetAddress(recipient);
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Invalid CC email address '{}' passed to sendEmail(). Skipping." + recipient, e);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```